# using Kal calendar from github

Tags: iphone

i am trying to use the kal calendar from following url

http://github.com/briancollins/Kal.

I have succesfully implemented this calendar in my code but now i want to get the date click event on the calendar in my viewcontroller where i have added this calendar. can someone please suggest me how can i do it?....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally added the source of the calendar and using same.